# Regex to remove spaces between \n in block of text

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I am trying to write a regex that will remove all spaces between occurrences of `\n`.

For example, the string `Test\n \n \n    \n\n 1234` would turn into `Test\n\n\n\n\n 1234`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why not use `.trim()` ?

Comment: @arnaud_h Probably because they want to keep the newlines.

Comment: Can use `.replaceAll()`

Comment: replacing this regex `^([\s\t]*)\n$` with "\n" would work? it should match every single line replacing the space part before the newline with nothing but a newline.

Comment: I think `\n +` would work.. just replace with new line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use non-greedy matching of whitespace `\s*?` bracketed by lookbehind and lookahead assertions for `\n`, (expressed as `(?<=\n)` and `(?=\n)` respectively) and replace it with an empty string.

```js
const input = "Test\n \n \n    \n\n 1234";
const result = input.replace(/(?<=\n)\s*?(?=\n)/g, '');

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let t = "test\n\n \n\n\n \n"

console.log(JSON.stringify(t.replaceAll(/(?<=\n)\s*?(?=\n)/g, '')))
```

Comment: I don't want to replace all spaces.  Just ones between newlines.